# List additional CUPS printer information

Tags: linux, printing, cups

How to display printer information, such as printer description or printer location using command line tools?

`lpstat -t` lists printer names, classes and devices for printers, but it doesn't list printer description or location. Is there a way to get this information without using http or GUI interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain this information with `lpstat -l -p printername`.

```
[root@Valley ~]# lpstat -l -p zebra2
printer zebra2 is idle.  enabled since Tue Jun  8 15:50:35 2010
        Form mounted:
        Content types: any
        Printer types: unknown
        Description: Zebra 105SL in shipping
        Alerts: none
        Location: Shipping
        Connection: direct
        On fault: no alert
        After fault: continue
        Users allowed:
                (all)
        Forms allowed:
                (none)
        Banner required
        Charset sets:
                (none)
        Default pitch:
        Default page size:
        Default port settings:
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  Do you know if the returned field names are locale aware, or will they always default to English?

Comment: I do not know, but you can check at cups.org and with your specific distribution of Linux.

Comment: Turns out it is.  Exporting `LANG=C` does the trick to force `en_US`.  If calling this command with Apple, an additional export `SOFTWARE=` (blank) needs to be provided to bypass the locale used by the desktop.  Why mention this?  If you are parsing the output of this command wight a script (e.g.  `grep "Description:"`), forcing locale is a good idea, or else the logic could fail on a non-English desktop/terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more global, for everything eliminate the grep statement.

```
for i in $( lpstat -v | awk '{ print $3 }' | tr ':' ' ' ) ; do lpstat -l -p $i | grep 'printer\|Location' ; done
```